# Discord.js Create webhook in every channel on server

Tags: discord.js

Hi how i can create webhook (with same name and avatar) in every channel of specific guild using discord.js?
And how to fetch first webhook and send messages using first webhook in specific channel using discord.js?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of but if you added this command, it should work. Run it in every channel

```js
const prefix = '';
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

if (msg.content === `${prefix}createwebhook`) {
  let name = args.slice(1).join(" ");
  
  //Check for permissions because we don't need everyone making webhooks!
  if(!message.author.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.send("You are not authorized to do this!");
  }
  //What if the bot can't do it?
  if(message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.send("I have not been allowed to make webhooks!");
  }

  message.channel.createWebhook(name, {
    avatar: args[1], // So when doing this command, you must give it an image URL (Should end in .jpg, .png, etc.)
}).then(webhook => console.log(`Created webhook ${webhook}`)).catch(console.error);

  message.channel.send(`${message.author}, created the webhook "${webhook}" with the profile picture ${args[0]}`);
  }
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/webhooks.html#creating-webhooks-with-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
I've have edited your file since you had an error with it so this verison should work.
```

Discord v12 Version

```
client.on("message", message =>{
  if(message.content === 'create-webhook') {
     if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.send("You are not authorized to do this!");

  } else if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
   //What if the bot can't do it?
    return message.channel.send("I have not been allowed to make webhooks!");

  } else if(message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.createWebhook("HOOK", {
    avatar: args[1], // So when doing this command, you must give it an image URL (Should end in .jpg, .png, etc.)
    

}).then(webhook => message.author.send(`created the webhook ${webhook.url}`)).catch(console.error);

  }
  }
})
```

Or if you have a command handler with commands in your folder.

```
const {Discord, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(client, message, args) =>{
  
message.delete()

  //Check for permissions because we don't need everyone making webhooks!
  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.send("You are not authorized to do this!");

  } else if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
   //What if the bot can't do it?
    return message.channel.send("I have not been allowed to make webhooks!");

  } else if(message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
    return message.channel.createWebhook("HOOK", {
    avatar: args[1], // So when doing this command, you must give it an image URL (Should end in .jpg, .png, etc.)
    

}).then(webhook => message.author.send(`created the webhook ${webhook.url}`)).catch(console.error);

  }
  
}
module.exports.help = {
  name: "create-webhook"
}
```